# How to connect to gmail server with App passwords via java imap?

Tags: java, gmail-imap

I am trying to get emails from my gmail account. But recently my code stop working via the Google disable Less secure App option. I want to use App passwords. But I can't find how I need to update my code.
My code

```
public static String getTextFromMessage(String host, String user, String password) {
        try {
            //create properties field
            Properties properties = new Properties();
            properties.put("mail.imap.host", host);
            properties.put("mail.imap.port", "993");
            properties.put("mail.imap.starttls.enable", "true");
            properties.put("mail.imap.ssl.trust", host);
            Session emailSession = Session.getDefaultInstance(properties);

            //create the IMAP store object and connect with the pop server
            Store store = emailSession.getStore("imaps");

            store.connect(host, user, password); // here is not working

            //create the folder object and open it
            Folder emailFolder = store.getFolder("Inbox");
            emailFolder.open(Folder.READ_ONLY);

            // retrieve the messages from the folder in an array and print it
            Message[] messages = emailFolder.getMessages();
...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use app password instead of regular one over here:

```
store.connect(host, user, password);
```

This should work.